# How to post a gist via the API (not anonymously)

Tags: node.js, github, github-api, axios, gist

I'm using `passport-github` strategy.

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: "...",
    clientSecret: "...",
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/login/github/return',
    scope: 'gist'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    return cb(null, profile);
  }));
```

Then I make the `POST` request

```
app.get('/profile/post',
  require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(),
  function(req, res){
var url = 'https://api.github.com/gists';

axios.post(url, {
  method: "POST",
  "description": "POSTING FROM EXPRESS",
  "public": true,
  "files": {
    "file1.txt": {
      "content": "EXPRESS "
    }

}
})
  .then(function (response) {...})
  .catch(function (error) { ... });
```

The gist gets created but anonymously.

I tried passing `"owner"` and `"user"` as part of the request arguments but no use. I also tried passing the username in the url

As far as I can see [the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist) say nothing about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the access token you get from passport authentication callback. For instance, using mongo with mongoose to store the user :

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
        clientID: "...",
        clientSecret: "...",
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/login/github/return'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        process.nextTick(function() {

            User.findOne({ id: profile.id }, function(err, res) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (res) {
                    console.log("user exists");
                    return done(null, res);
                } else {
                    console.log("insert user");
                    var user = new User({
                        id: profile.id,
                        access_token: accessToken,
                        refresh_token: refreshToken
                    });
                    user.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    }
));
```

Then when you deserialize the user, you get the user back with the access token :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({ "id": id }, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

and now in your endpoint, put `req.user.access_token` in `Authorization` header of github API request :

```
app.get('/profile/post', 
  require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(),
  function(req, res) {

    axios.post('https://api.github.com/gists', {
      "method": "POST",
      "description": "POSTING FROM EXPRESS",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization" : "token " + req.user.access_token
      },
      "public": true,
      "files": {
        "file1.txt": {
          "content": "EXPRESS "
        }
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {...})
    .catch(function (error) { ... });
  }
);
```

But instead of building the request manually, you can use [octonode](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode) library that do it for you. You can find a complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/35b4a063d8b75fc1b50f23863c4a7c75) of passport-github with octonode and mongodb